# Producing squiggles using your abstract-syntax-tree

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

**The situation:**

I have crafted a scanner, parser and various AST classes for a little used programming language, a hobby project of mine. The parser, with the help of the scanner, builds a heterogenous AST which I do some manipulations on. In the past I have created a plugins/add-ins for some IDEs for syntax highlighting and some other elements.

The problem lies in the errors: the parser generates some and has access to the tokens that constitute a statement. Some errors only arise later however, such as being unable to resolve an identifier. I would like to display squiggles under such identifiers or other faulty tokens. Not just that, I like the ability to manipulate my AST nodes without losing all comments, spacing and so forth in my original document.

When creating a new Statement in my AST I can easily add the tokens that make up this statement as children. But ...

**The question:**

If reasonably doable I wish to include support for displaying squiggles. This requires a statement to be aware of where the tokens that make up the statement are positioned. Unfortunately, a statement has variations that sometimes include more Tokens, sometimes less tokens. If I were making a read-only AST, this would not be a problem. However, I wish my AST to be read-write for refactoring purposes! This means that altering a statement in the AST essentially means adding Tokens (the children of a Statement) and thus the Statement class should be capable of reparsing itself.

**This would polute the AST with parsing code and no longer maintaining seperation of concerns!**

**Technical details:**

One alternative is to turn the AssignmentStatement into a factory, getting a set of tokens, producing an instance of the statement and constantly have it be aware of its own tokens.

An AST-node for assignments in my case is basically be like this at the moment:

A hierarchical sample AST could be:

```
AssemblyDeclaration
    .. Statement ..
    .. Statement ..
    ClassDeclaration
       .. Token .. // one or more that make up the entire class statement
       .. Token .. // one or more that make up the entire class statement
       Statement(s)
         .. Token .. // Which have their own tokens that make up the statement .. and possibly have sub-nodes of their own such as Expressions which have -their- own Tokens that comprise it.
```

A conceptual idea of the base ast node, the parent for everything in the syntax tree, no matter if it is a class declaration, statement or token.

```
public abstract class BaseAstNode : IList<BaseAstNode>
{
    ... implementation of IList<BaseAstNode>
    ... implementation of Visitor Pattern
    ... implementation of Clonable
}    

public sealed class AssignmentStatement : BaseAstNode 
{
public Expression Expression { get; set; }; // Setting this will alter the Tokens (children!) of this node, possibly even ADD Tokens!
public TypeReference Target { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PrimitiveNumberExpression : Expression // is a BaseAstNode
{
public int Value { get; set; } // Setting this will alter the Tokens (children!) of this node!
}

public abstract class Token : BaseAstNode
{
    public Layers Layer { get; set; }
    public TokenType TokenType { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Line { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public abstract int Length { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString(){}
}
```

*How do others solve this problem? Is this the right way?*

Comment: How does your current code construct AssignmentStatement objects?

Comment: var stmt = new AssignmentStatement { Expression = Expression.Null, Target = TypeReference.Null }; .. only then with the expressions and reference produced by the parser.

Comment: I guess my question is how to the members get populated with data, and why can't the class also be populated with a start and length value?

Comment: The statements, part of the syntax tree, get populated by the Parser. Each statement can easily get a start and end-tag. But I still couldn't put squiggles under my, say, identifier unless I started tracking all the tokens the statement is made up of and -their- positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the code for the statement where the error occurred, you should be able to re-parse the individual statement, this time tracking the location of the tokens and noting those that are invalid (since you didn't have the locations of the tokens saved the first time around).  At least you don't have to parse the whole document over, just one line... perhaps re-using some of the parsing code you already have.

Alternatively, *do* store the location of every token (start and length in the document) so you can easily access the position of that token when you need to refer to its source.  Why not do that?

Some possible optimizations, if you can re-generate the token text from the token object, would be to not store the token length, or just search for that text within the line, assuming you want to do the same thing to every occurrence of that token on the line (or all lines).

**Edit:** Now that you have the linked the tokens to the original source code from which they were parsed, you'd need to link the statements to the tokens from which they were parsed.  There are two ways you could do this:

1. Add a List<Token> member to the BaseAstNode. OR
2. Add specific Token members to each derived statement class so you know exactly which token links to which part of the statement.

Now you have a chain all the way from the statement to the source code so you can identify the source code associated with each part of each statement.

**Edit 2:** If you are trying to figure out how the actual parsing would process tokens into BaseAstNode-derived objects, I have not yet considered that question (it wasn't very clear that this was part of the question). Since I have not done this before, my suggestion may not be the best on the first attempt. But hopefully it can be refined as necessary. My first thoughts lead me to the System.Xml namespace, which also implement a parser. Perhaps some of your design can be modeled after the XML parsers and related classes. XmlNode is probably similar to your BaesAstNode class. XmlElement is probably analogous to your Token class.  XmlDocument is a specialization of XmlNode that handles all the parsing in one LoadXml function, which populates the object with children.

So following the Xml namespace's example, you could make ParseCode be a member of ClassDeclaration that populates the object with all the appropriate child objects. It could accept a string or an ordered collection of tokens as input, and add derived instances of BaseAstNode to an ordered collection of BaseAstNode objects stored in the class.  But not all of the parsing could would need to be in one function.  As you are parsing text or tokens, I assume you would start out in the ParseCode function, pushing parsed tokens onto a stack or queue until you have parsed enough tokens to uniquely identify what kind of statement you are parsing, then pass those queued tokens and the current state of the parser to an appropriate derived parser on one of the statement classes.  When the derived class finishes parsing the tokens that define the statement, the tokens would be added to the statement, then the calling code would add the parsed statement to the parent collection of statements.

Comment: I have rewritten my question to include the details you have asked for and some extra edits for clarity. IF what I described is what you propose I have some additional questions about who is responsible for parsing and tracking tokens into ast-nodes. Have a look at the new info!

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I was thinking.  I probably wouldn't store Position and Column independently; I would probably calculate one from the other and the original text, if I even needed both.  To be honest, I have not done this before, but I generally do alright solving new problems :).  So what questions remain... who was responsible for parsing tokens before, and why does that have to change?

Comment: Actually looking at it more closely, I was kind of thinking you'd want to track the position of everything (BaseAstNode) and not just tokens.  But if you think Tokens are the only things whose position you will care about, you could go with what you have proposed.

Comment: Not at all-- I do want to track everything. Whitespace, comment, language elements. All these are tokens. A statement as such will consist out of whitespace, comment, end of lines and language tokens. Token (ast) nodes are those with Length and thus determine line & column. As for parsing-- if a statement node should be able to understand its own elements, it must parse this pile of tokens that make up itself into a valid statement keeping in mind optional keywords that may or not be there.

Comment: I guess I am having difficulty understanding the relationship between objects like AssignmentStatement and Token.  Is AssignmentStatement another level up from token such that you first parse everything into tokens, and then parse them into higher level classes, but they're all derived from BaseAstNode?  And there's no relationship between the levels?  Have you considered adding relationships between the higher levels just like you just added between Tokens and the original source?

Comment: Conceptually, the lowest level is the Token, derived of the BaseAstNode. Above the Token node, again conceptually, is the statement node, comprised of a set of tokens. (Consider the tokens in the tree the 'parse tree'). The statements could be considered the AST, overlaying the token (-level). Normally, you don't even have to have all the tokens. But since I want to manipulate the original token set through the AST... am I making it clearer?

Comment: So can you now link the statements to the tokens to support the desired behavior, as described in my newly edited answer?

Comment: This is more or less what I am doing. Hence my earlier question about parsing-- if statements are directly manipulating the tokens they comprise of then they must understand their own form-- and thus be able to parse the tokens into the components that make up the statements in order to edit them. Yes? What is a convenient way for this? Nice scroller library incidentally.

Comment: If you were linking your statements to your tokens, then you would not have any problem locating the code from which a statement was derived.  But based on your code above, you don't appear to have any such link. And based on your question, that's what appears to be missing -- some way to identify which tokens a statement is built from.  You say that your AST tree doesn't contain any details beyond the statement level.  My point is that you need to link it to the tokens so that it does. Am I missing something?  Do you need help generating statements from tokens in a way that maintains a link?

Comment: I have added Edit 2 as a result of re-reading and re-interpreting your question to try to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. Yes, Statements contain the tokens that make up that statement as children. But the statement should be able to add or remove them as the statement changes! I updated the question in various places to explain. You get polution of parsing logic in your syntax tree and loose seperation of concerns!

Comment: When you talk about the statement changing, are you talking about the source code underlying the statement changing, requiring the statement to be re-parsed, or some other kind of change (which I'll need help understanding)?  Is the key to be able to re-parse a statement without re-parsing the whole document?

Comment: The scanner turns source code into Tokens, these are turned by the Parser into the tree of Statements and it adds Tokens to these to make sure they know how they were constructed. This is one-way, read only. When writing to the tree, new Tokens (or even Statements!) can be introduced -by- those changes. And this modified tree, with modified Statements and Tokens should be able to be written back. Read-write! Changing these Tokens means the statement is build up differently and needs to be able to know the changed locations of its own modified set of Tokens! Thus .. reparse itself!

Comment: I'm still confused by the fact that the statements are being changed directly. What exactly is initiating these changes? Do these changed generate new source code, or does new source code generate these changes?  You say the tree is one-way read only, but then jump right into talking about writing to it... who is writing to it?  Why can't the tokens whose position are after inserted tokens be appropriately adjusted as the new code is generated/parsed?

Comment: No, if I go from code to ast it is a read-only tree. But when I modify the tree I want to write back the source in its modified state, keeping all comments and formatting. Like refactoring in VS2010. I have accepted your answer because you have provided some new thoughts and insights. I will evaluate further solutions.

Comment: OK, so let's assume that you can identify the line(s) of source code on which a modification occurred (you have that in every token) and also assume that you can identify a BaseAstNode-derived class that has a parse method that can parse a block of code that entirely includes the modified lines. For every BaseAstNode that has a parse function, I would also create a function "GenerateCode" that could re-generate the code. Replace the old lines with the new results of GenerateCode, then call Parse and replace the BaseAstNodes with the new result. Then adjust line numbers of all subsequent nodes.